# Preprocessing Scala parser Reader input

Tags: parsing, scala, combinators

I have a file containing a text representation of an object. I have written a combinator parser grammar that parses the text and returns the object. In the text, "#" is a comment delimiter: everything from that character to the end of the line is ignored. Blank lines are also ignored. I want to process text one line at a time, so that I can handle very large files.

I don't want to clutter up my parser grammar with generic comment and blank line logic. I'd like to remove these as a preprocessing step. Converting the file to an iterator over line I can do something like this:

```
Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.map(_.replaceAll("#.*", "").trim).filter(!_.isEmpty)
```

How can I pass the output of an expression like that into a combinator parser? I can't figure out how to create a `Reader` object out of a filtered expression like this. The Java `FileReader` interface doesn't work that way.

Is there a way to do this, or should I put my comment and blank line logic in the parser grammar? If the latter, is there some `util.parsing` package that already does this for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the `fromLines` method on `PagedSeq`:

```
import scala.collection.immutable.PagedSeq
import scala.io.Source
import scala.util.parsing.input.PagedSeqReader

val lines = Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.map(
  _.replaceAll("#.*", "").trim
).filterNot(_.isEmpty)

val reader = new PagedSeqReader(PagedSeq.fromLines(lines))
```

And now you've got a `scala.util.parsing.input.Reader` that you can plug into your parser. This is essentially what happens when you parse a `java.io.Reader`, anyway—it immediately gets wrapped in a `PagedSeqReader`.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest code you'll ever write, but you could go through a new `Source` as follows:

```
val SEP = System.getProperty("line.separator")
def lineMap(fileName : String, trans : String=>String) : Source = {
  Source.fromIterable(
    Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.flatMap(
      line => trans(line) + SEP
    ).toIterable
  )
}
```

Explanation: `flatMap` will produce an iterator on *characters*, which you can turn into an `Iterable`, which you can use to build a new `Source`. You need the extra `SEP` because `getLines` removes it by default (using `\n` may not work as `Source` will not properly separate the lines).

If you want to apply filtering too, i.e. remove some of the lines, you could for instance try:

```
// whenever `trans` returns `None`, the line is dropped.
def lineMapFilter(fileName : String, trans : String=>Option[String]) : Source = {
  Source.fromIterable(
    Source.fromFile(fileName).getLines.flatMap(
      line => trans(line).map(_ + SEP).getOrElse("")
    ).toIterable
  )
}
```

As an example:

```
lineMapFilter("in.txt", line => if(line.isEmpty) None else Some(line.reverse))
```

...will remove empty lines and reverse non-empty ones.